# Index/Max/Min of a Vector<double> C++

Tags: c++, vector, max, min

I want to be able to figure out the highest and lowest element in an vector and also figure out what position/index that high/low number is currently.
For example,

```
vector<double> x;
std::cout << "Enter in #s: ";
double numbers;
std::getline(std::cin, numbers);
x.push_back(numbers);
```

Let's say the user inputted 4.3 1.0 2.99 43.5

I would want the result to say

```
The highest number is 43.5 at position 4
The lowest number is 1.0 at position 2
```

I was wondering if there is any way to implement this code WITHOUT using the min_element/max_element function and do it with a for loop?

I wanted to use something like:

```
for (int i=0;i < x.size();i++)
    if ( //the number is less than ) {
        std::cout << "The lowest number is...... at position .....";
    if ( //the number is greather than ) {
        std::cout << "The highest number is......at position......";
```

Comment: wow, they are awefully close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you need to store both the indices of the highest and lowest elements, comparing them with the current element for each iteration.

```
// Note: the below code assumes that the container (vector) is not empty
//    you SHOULD check if the vector contains some elements before executing the code below

int hi, lo;    // These are indices pointing to the highest and lowest elements
hi = lo = 0;   // Set hi and lo to the first element's index

// Then compare the elements indexed by hi and lo with the rest of the elements
for (int i = 1;i < x.size();i++) {
    if(x[i] < x[lo]) {
        // The element indexed by i is less than the element indexed by lo
        //    so set the index of the current lowest element to i
        lo = i;
    }
    // Below, else if is used and not if because the conditions cannot be both true
    else if(x[i] > x[hi]) {
        // Same logic as the above, only for the highest element
        hi = i;
    }
}

// Note: the position indicated by the output below will be 0-based
std::cout << "The lowest number is " << x[lo] << " at position " << lo << ".\n";
std::cout << "The highest number is " << x[hi] << " at position " << hi << ".\n";
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/805d7468bef84f92)

Answer (score 3):

Compare each number to the best max / min found so far.
If it is bigger/smaller replace the max/min with it and note the index

You will need a max and min variable and two indexes - be carefull what you set the initial value if your max and min to

Answer (score 0):

```
    size_t iMax=0,iMin=0;
    for(size_t i=1; i<x.size(); ++i)
    {
            if(x[iMax] < x[i])
                    iMax=i;
            if(x[iMin] > x[i])
                    iMin=i;
    }
    //iMax is index of the biggest num in the array
```